# CSS, CENTERED element over Google Maps

Tags: css, html, google-maps-api-3

I have a GoogleMaps on my website.
My problem is CSS, how to do a CENTERED div that is positioned over Google Maps?

[image]

```
<div style="position:relative">
   <div style="width:300px; height:300px" id="map_localization"></div>
   <div style="position:absolute; width:100px; margin:0px auto;">CENTERED</div>
</div>
```

This is what almost works for me, but need to put the CENTERED layer OVER the map

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, I tried and did it very well. Then I decided to ask you at stackoverflow.

Comment: Could you post your code? Its hard to create a CSS rule without markup. And post a link to your current page demonstrating the problem (if available).

Comment: People. Whats wrong with you? If I could do it I would NOT ask you. If I could find it I would NOT ask you. The only reason I am asking you a question is I CANNOT do it.

Comment: Show us what you CAN do! That's all we are asking, help us help you. Include the markup & CSS that you have generated so far in your attempts. By saying I cannot do it, you mean you have not tried at all? If you cannot do anything at all, then you have two options. 1. Go learn the stuff yourself. 2. Hire a developer who can do this for you. Your life and our life just gets sweeter if you help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you reveal some code?

I would do it by putting both the map and the div to be centered within a relative positioned div. Then I would absolute position both the map and the div inside.

I would center the div inside with absolute positioning: http://www.zachgraeve.com/2006/10/01/center-abosulte-position-div/

Specifically, the CSS of the div to be centered would look something like this.

```
#divToBeCentered {
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px;
}
```

---

Update

Actually, this fiddle I made illustrates what I meant by putting both the map and another div in a containing div:

http://jsfiddle.net/2zaxd/

Here's the HTML (similar to what you had).

```
<div id="containerForAll">
   <div id="map_localization"></div>
   <div id="divToBeCentered">CENTERED</div>
</div>​
```

and the CSS.

```
#containerForAll, #map_localization, #divToBeCentered {
 border: 1px solid #000;   
}

#containerForAll {
 position: relative; 
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;   
}

#map_localization, #divToBeCentered {
  position: absolute;
}

#map_localization {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

#divToBeCentered {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 margin-left: -50px;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -50px;
}
```

​This centers the inner div above your map via absolute positioning.

Comment: Hmm, could you please reveal what you're doing so far?

Comment: I am doing it as an Android project through Phonegap. Just, please, give me a while to cut it and post here.

Comment: David, the problem is I do not want to have my map centered. I want to have a map anywhere, but the div that is over the map should be centered (according to the map).

Comment: I see, how about just not center the containing div and just center the contained div then? In other words, both `#divToBeCentered` and the map fit into a single relative positioned div. This outer div you can place anywhere you want as you said.

Comment: David, I've just put some extra info to the top post. Any chance I am close to the solution?